# How to show all columns of database tables in windows form in labels c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am new to c#. i am making point of sale. How to show all the data from sql table in labels? Kindly help me or give me some suggestion.

Form:

[image]

Table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a listbox and set the datasource and displaymember with the model of your data that you extract using a stored procedure for example.